# How do I ensure that every method of a class must have fixed set of parameters

Tags: typescript

Let us say I have a class `Controller` which has some set of methods. I want my `controller` class methods to have 3 parameters of some type. How do I ensure that every method in a class implement methods in a defined way

I tried with the interface but did not succeed

```js
   /**
   * I want every method of the UserController class to
   * have req, res and next as parameters. Parameters
   * other than req, res and next should not be allowed
   */

   class UserController {
      // correct implementation, as this method has
      // req, res and next as a parameter
      public async login(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
         // do some login stuff here
      }

      // wrong implementation, as req, res and next are missing
      public async signup(username, password) {
         // do some signup stuff here
      }
   }
```

I know I can create an interface for UserController that defines each and every method of UserController with fixed set of parameters. But I want a more general solution which should force the developer to follow a set pattern. If I use interface, I will have to check for the correct implementation of Controller at each code review process.

Comment: I'm afraid that is not possible.

Comment: does it sounds logical to have such a feature in typescript? Perhaps we can use something in the interface like:

interface {
  *(): (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => Promise<void>;
}

Comment: One issue is that `signup()` *does* match `(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => Promise<void>`, because `username` and `password` implicitly have `any` types, which match anything, and [you can always implement a function using fewer parameters than its call signature](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters) so the third parameter can be left out.  There's no good, clean way to enforce that the *implementation* matches; only that it can be *called* that way.

Comment: If you change your `signup()` example so that `username` and `password` are annotated as `string` or something *incompatible*, we can make *that* show up as an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you'd like to have a `UserController` class where each method (that is, each function-valued property) exactly matches a certain call signature, like this:

```
type AcceptableMethod = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => Promise<void>;
type NextFunction = { noIdeaWhatYouWantHere(): void };
```

(I created a dummy `NextFunction` type so as to avoid errors in a standalone IDE).

Well, you can do it, although it's less pretty than I'd like.  As I mentioned in the comments, [a function which takes fewer parameters is assignable to a function which takes more parameters](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters); so a method that looks like `async foo(){}` will match `AcceptableMethod` because the compiler doesn't want to require that `foo()` take any parameters... since that is the same as it taking those parameters and ignoring them.  Whether or not you agree with that (and there are some times when you should), it makes this a bit more cumbersome because we'll need to check the number of parameters manually.

Anyway, we can do it by constraining `UserController` to implement `MeetsConstraints<UserController>`, where `MeetsConstraints<T>` is compatible with `T` if and only if it meets your constraints.  Let's describe the constraints in words.  For each property key `K` of `T` (and the corresponding value `T[K]`):

- If `T[K]` is a function type, then:

  - it should have exactly the number of parameters as `AcceptableMethod`,
  - and it should be compatible with `AcceptableMethod`
- Otherwise, if it's not a function type, `T[K]` can be anything.

Here's a way to translate that into code:

```
type MeetsConstraints<T> = { [K in keyof T]:
  T[K] extends (...args: any) => any ? (
    ParamsLength<T[K]> extends ParamsLength<AcceptableMethod> ? AcceptableMethod :
    T[K] extends AcceptableMethod ? Invalid<
      ["Expected", ParamsLength<AcceptableMethod>, "parameters, got", ParamsLength<T[K]>]
    > : AcceptableMethod
  ) : T[K]
};
```

We need to define `ParamsLength<>`:

```
type ParamsLength<F extends (...args: any)=>any> = Parameters<F>['length'];
```

And let's talk about `Invalid<>`. If `T[K]` matches `AcceptableMethod` but does not have the right number of parameters, we need to return an error condition that prevents the `K` property from matching.  The easiest way to do that is to return a type of `never`, but then the error message is completely incomprehensible: `()=>Promise<void> is not assignable to never`.  Instead, we'd like to use an "invalid" type which causes an error but lets us print a custom message.  [Unfortunately this doesn't exist in TypeScript as of TS3.5](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23689), so we need a workaround.  Here it is:

```
type Invalid<T> = T & Error; // workaround for Microsoft/TypeScript#23689
```

It produces an error which is a *bit* better... something like `()=>Promise<void> is not assignable to ["Expected", 3, "parameters, got", 0]`.  Hopefully someone who sees that will have some clue what to do.

---

Okay, let's test it!

```
class UserController implements MeetsConstraints<UserController> {

  public okayStringProp = "a"; // okay
  public okayObjectProp = { a: 1 }; // okay
  public okayArrayProp = [1, 2, 3]; // okay

  public async okayMethod(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) { } // okay

  public badMethod1() { return 17; } // error! 
  //     ~~~~~~~~~~ <-- number is not Promise<void>;

  public async badMethod2() { return 17; } // error!
  //           ~~~~~~~~~~ <-- number is not void

  public async badMethod3() { } // error!
  //           ~~~~~~~~~~ <-- error message is the best I can do here:
  // () => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type '["Expected", 3, "parameters, got", 0]'

  public async badMethod4(username: string) { } // error!
  //           ~~~~~~~~~~ <-- Request not assignable to string

  public async badMethod5(x: Request, y: Response, z: NextFunction, oops: number) {} // err!
  //           ~~~~~~~~~~ <-- 
  // (x: Request, y: Response, z: NextFunction, oops: number) => Promise<void>' 
  // is not assignable to type 'AcceptableMethod'

  public async signup(username: any, password: any) { } // error!
  //           ~~~~~~ <-- error message is the best I can do here:
  // ["Expected", 3, "parameters, got", 2]

}
```

As you can see, all the non-method properties are allowed, and the desired method signature is allowed.  All other methods give you an error of some type.

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBAggxnCZgEMBGAbCBZCwAWA9gCZQC8UAFAE4QCOAXFAEr0CuEAzsADRS2cmrTmEIA7ThD5iIAD2BMAcnOAAxNmLjAAluICU5AHxQACtUIBbbZIA8AN0LbihgNwAoUJCjL56zTvFyKABvKDFCAEliCBQAdXwUYABNQjZYlDFgAAkIWko9JgcnKABfdw9waFw8TgBhcW5qFG1MzhsAFWMKUIBtAGkoFqgAawgQQgAzKHaAXQY3KGn+magVCDFiTioAOl2UagBzQSgMkAMyY1OoAH4qBcXTfZQLTgAZdYOCDuXjNY2tkxPF7vMSffA2eCIZDoLC4AgkYy3SFIVCYHB4IikeYPJZ9FZ-TawBAomHo+GkW4RMR2FAYJw2e44noAIgAorJIFoIMRmXxAU1gR8vsjoWi4ZjDHxmWAgXhcpw+AdCMBeY8BW8heD2j8ZoyoMYmCLUbCMSR7gYmNq8W4ym4Kl5+c8NaCvqpVvJ1oTKLttvsjkxTudLmIQF01c85dQ2qpDD0AORYF34OMzdyeaBUml04gdMPtKAAMigrOo5moLigAHpK1AAO6EajDfapDZQCYNqD4YDAMCCasHbQENhobZwSyV7DaODmTiTYCV9qVADK0+0yEr1k4HE4lYATABmABsAA4AJx2txwDAoThbACqkmo9Uy5gwWGogwsYCwFnWwC21T-s+jTNK0NgPrkz7AK+77GMEdqLGAw50nAUCEE2IBLtBLQHGYhBgEEzIoMy7iIchU5oRhADyaAAFYQFoeEEd0JxMAAjKUpFQEhmAUehKAgDApYCUxQQ9GxfC7nw+6pgh3HkahN4gJolECeKJA0PQQjsFwvD8Fw2kiA0UhhCoSgqH4Wi6GIBihCUVY1vxIByTxKFQGgKDEOpxBsfkIT6cAbDUGIUBsQA7BW9nVqspYNgAhFA9zRTiAB+aXpRlUA2AAtNlYRsBYaC5IMWzhMApjmFYthFM45RkbximcMpqEeV5prELufmhLQgXBaFEWlA5MVlnFSU1jiE1QBl00pVluX5YVxXWGEypQDVLkKScTUqa13n7l1g3RbkI1jZNE0zZlOV5cdHa-reKAHNAy0ENARXcFAERQHAGRQMQhCdrkEDYkNfkXBVljWBA9iOM4cYlSt5U3pw2gHGIpJQMA-3plAcYsuynLANyqr7lKMoCpGCpQEqKp8AADDMcYbQ1W3Ne5nneQALJQbCPmjv5MI0OG2YdNY3dQo2LMlZ2LBd6VzXlrB0Nu5VlVtyOo+jmNQILoJM25Sk7ez7UAKyULI2lK7pfAgIZogSCZABe5m+BoVniHwhD4ccYgFUV1DC1FouxeLp3SzLsuzVdiWSzWZsW8r1u28ZfBO94FmuwEYge17TA+4t-tGODVVQzVhhw6dy2q0jKNo2iGNY5UONGqS3mM-crkUQbqHqz7YDc7zEYBiGfAyre9bUMQQ9nP5gfDfFodhzN8tzx+d2cA9T1bC97m6R9X0-X9AO0MD0V4xyDGEzy0mk7KhNRoqyqqruuo2m4QA)

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you so much for your answer. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach to @jcalz method is to check that the method is *exactly* the same by type checking in both directions:

```ts
type AcceptableMethod = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => Promise<void>;
type NextFunction = { noIdeaWhatYouWantHere(): void };

type MeetsConstraints<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function 
    ? AcceptableMethod extends T[K] ? AcceptableMethod : never
    : T[K]
}
```

The trick here is in the `AcceptableMethod extends T[K]` which will fail (going to `never`) if the method has too few parameters.

Here is the same test getting all the errors but with *much worse error messages*.

```ts
class UserController implements MeetsConstraints<UserController> {

  public okayStringProp = "a";
  public okayObjectProp = { a: 1 };
  public okayArrayProp = [1, 2, 3];

  public async okayMethod(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) { } // okay

  public badMethod1() { return 17; } // error! 
  //     ~~~~~~~~~~ <-- Type '() => number' is not assignable to type 'never'.

  public async badMethod2() { return 17; } // error!
  //           ~~~~~~~~~~ <-- Type '() => Promise<number>' is not assignable to type 'never'.

  public async badMethod3() { } // error!
  //           ~~~~~~~~~~ <-- Type '() => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'never'.

  public async badMethod4(username: string) { } // error!
  //           ~~~~~~~~~~ <-- Type '(username: string) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'never'.

  public async badMethod5(x: Request, y: Response, z: NextFunction, oops: number) { } // error!
  //           ~~~~~~~~~~ <--Type '(x: Request, y: Response, z: NextFunction, oops: number) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'AcceptableMethod'.

  public async signup(username: any, password: any) { } // error!
  //           ~~~~~~ <-- Type '(username: any, password: any) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'never'.

}
```